# How can I use Mono.Unix on Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, mono, monodevelop

I have a C# app originally written in Windows that I'm now running in Linux on MonoDevelop. It works fine but now I need to recognise symbolic links. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19428170/detecting-symbolic-links-and-pipes-in-mono) answer but when I add:

```
using Mono.Unix;
```

I get the error "The type or namespace name 'Unix' does not exist in the namespace 'Mono'. Are you missing an assembly reference (CS0234)?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do what the error message says. Unintuitively, `Mono.Unix` lives in `Mono.Posix.dll`, so you need to add that as reference.

Comment: Bit surprised that MonoDevelop doesn't have Mono.Posix in its standard Reference list. I had to add it from /usr/lib/mono/4.0/Mono.Posix.dll

Comment: My MonoDevelop does list it.

Comment: I'm using MonoDevelop 4.0.12 on Ubuntu x64 14.04.

Comment: And me, 5.7 (git). No guarantees that the MD version is relevant to this issue though. Could be a mono installation difference. Haven't checked how MD populates that list.